# Missing required architecture arm64 in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I'm getting the error "missing required architecture arm64 in file /user/location/myframework.a(2 slices)" when I compile my project to the iPad mini, it refers to a specific third party framework that I'm using. This error does not show up for any of the older arm7 devices.

I know that this framework should be compiled to support the arm64 framework so to debug I created a second project that was completely blank except for this framework and it compiles just fine for the iPad mini. I used some of the functionality of the framework just to be sure it was actually being used by the project and it worked just fine.

So I'm 100% sure the issue isn't with the framework but with my project settings or something. I figured it might be that the old framework was still being cached somewhere so I cleaned and rebuilt, I deleted derived data, I removed the framework completely rebuilt and then added it back in. Nothing made a difference, it still comes up with the error "missing required architecture arm64 in file /user/location/myframework.a(2 slices)"

What might possibly be causing this problem?

EDIT:
I should have mentioned that the project installs fine on the iPad mini when the above framework is not included in the project. arm64 is listed as a valid architecture in the project settings.

Comment: did set your architecture as support 64 bit

Answer (score 6):

if not include 64 bit please include 64 bit

[image]

Comment: I just edited the question to mention that I had already done this, and that the project builds and installs on the iPad mini fine without the use of the framework in question.

Comment: @Tiddly referred setting needs to be applied to all libraries, not only the app project. Or was it something else? Above solution worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

According to lipo -info, the included SDK only has i386 and x86_64 architectures.

Comment: That's not correct because iOS devices don't run on Intel